# How to run "git clone ssh" with ansible and pass a password after the command is ran?

Tags: ansible

Friends,

I need to write an ansible task, which clones a git repository on a remote machine. I tryed like this:

```
- name: CLONING EMPTY REPOSITORY
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    chdir: /home/marcio/devdir
    cmd: git clone ssh://username@194.169.0.18/home/marcio/devdir/fresco.git fresco.local
```

Ansible is configured to become sudo when necessary and this is working fine, the above task, however, never finishes executing because the password of the user "marcio" must be provided after the `git clone` command is ran.

Since the original repository is located on the same machine where it will be cloned, I tryed generating a public key and storing it on the authorized_keys file of the server, but it didn't work as well.

Does anybody know a way to pass this password as a variable or another way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expect:

```
- name: CLONING EMPTY REPOSITORY
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    chdir: /home/marcio/devdir
    command: git clone ssh://username@194.169.0.18/home/marcio/devdir/fresco.git fresco.local
    responses:
      "YOUR ACTUAL LOGIN PROMPT": username
      "YOUR ACTUAL PASSWORD PROMPT": password
```